# Como intercalar um array?

Tags: python, array, algoritmo, lista

Estou escrevendo um programa que intercala os valores de dois arrays, com a mesma quantidade de valores. O programa recebe como entrada quantidade de valores em cada array. Em seguida, recebe os valores e, no fim, imprime os valores intercalados, da seguinte forma:

Entrada:

```
3
2
7
5
9
6
8
```

Saída:

```
2
9
7
6
5
8
```

Como estou fazendo:

```
quantidade = int(raw_input())
inicio = 0
lista1 = list()
while inicio < quantidade:
    valor = int(raw_input())
    inicio = inicio + 1
    lista1.append(valor)
```

Meu código cria uma lista com os valores recebidos, mas não sei como fazer para criar as duas listas, nem como intercalar os valores. Como proceder?

Comment: Você quer unir duas listas?

Comment: Eu quero intercalar os valores das listas. A quantidade de valores em cada lista deve ser fornecida pelo usuário no início. Exemplo: Lista 1 = [1, 2, 3], Lista 2 = [4, 5, 6], Lista de valores intercalados = [1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você deve fazer uma interação entre duas lista para conseguir intercalar elas, uma maneira de fazer esta interação entre elas é obter o [interator](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterador) da lista com o método `zip()`, e separa os elementos delas.

Veja este exemplo:

```
def intercala(L,L2):
    intercalada = []
    for a,b in zip(L, L2):
        intercalada.append(a)
        intercalada.append(b)
    return intercalada

lista1 = [1,2,3]
lista2 = [4,5,6]

listaIntercalada = intercala(lista1, lista2)

for i in listaIntercalada:
    print i
```

Saída:

> 1
>   4
>   2
>   5
>   3
>   6

**Explicação**

Criei um método responsável por intercalar as listas `intercala()` que retorna a lista intercalada, os dados que são passados para ele como parâmetros são duas listas, desta forma é possível obter o que deseja.

Consulte a [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) do método `zip()` para saber mais.

Comment: Consultarei. Obrigado!

Comment: Muito boa a resposta.