# Intercalação de vetores em python

Tags: python-3.x

Faça um programa que preencha dois vetores de cinco elementos numéricos cada um e mostre o vetor resultante da intercalação deles. Os vetores devem ser inicializados com a valores abaixo:

https://photos.app.goo.gl/egHj5dYLAXxfbLoW6

Primeiro resolvi fazer uma versão mais reduzida, onde o terceiro vetor terá apenas 5 elementos.
Consegui isso aqui(caso a visualização esteja confusa, o código tá mais organizado no Google docs: 
https://docs.google.com/document/d/13poguwUMA4y3mumadOkDJgarwzqx_vr-HkZgw9MMmg4/edit?usp=drivesdk):

```
vetor1 = [0]*5
vetor1[0] = 4
vetor1[1] = -9
vetor1[2] = 78
vetor1[3] = 0
vetor1[4] = 25
print(vetor1)

vetor2 = [0]*5
vetor2[0] = 8
vetor2[1]= 2
vetor2[2] = 34
vetor2[3] = 90
vetor2[4]= 200
print(vetor2)

v3 = [0] * 5

for i in range(5):
    if i%2 == 0:
        v3[i]  = vetor1[i/2]
    else:
```

E é aqui que começo a ter problemas. Não consigo achar uma fórmula pra relacionar todos os índices de v3 e de v2.

Answer (score 4):

Usando listas em compreensão (nomeadamente `[ x | par ∈ zip(a,b) ∧ x ∈ par ]`):

```
a=[4, -9, 78, 0, 25]                                                                          
b=[8, 2, 34, 90, 200] 
print([x for par in zip(a,b) for x in par])
```

Saída:

```
[4, 8, -9, 2, 78, 34, 0, 90, 25, 200]
```

Comment: Muito mais pythonica!  +1

Comment: Não entendi o funcionamento da estrutura " x for par in zip(a,b)"

Comment: @PabloLeonardo em linguagem matemática, isto costuma escrever-se como `[ x | par ∈ zip(a,b) ∧ x ∈ par ]`

Answer (score 4):

Uma forma trivial de se resolver isso é utilizando a estrutura `itertools.chain` em conjunto com a `zip`:

```py
from itertools import chain

a = [4, -9, 78, 0, 25]                                                                          
b = [8, 2, 34, 90, 200]

resultado = chain.from_iterable(zip(a, b))

print(*resultado)
# 4 8 -9 2 78 34 0 90 25 200
```

A classe `zip` irá gerar um objeto iterável que produzirá tuplas com os dois valores respectivos a cada posição das listas e a função `chain.from_iterable` irá *aplanar* essa estrutura com todos os valores em um mesmo nível. O retorno é um gerador, pois isso foi necessário o `*` para consumí-lo e exibir os valores.

O código em Python equivalente para esse trecho seria:

```py
def intercalar(a, b):
  for i, j in zip(a, b):
    yield i
    yield j
```

Ou de maneira mais genérica, sem limitar à duas listas:

```py
def intercalar(*listas):
  for valores in zip(*listas):
    for valor in valores:
      yield valor
```

Ou ainda:

```py
def intercalar(*listas):
  for valores in zip(*listas):
    yield from valores
```

Answer (score 3):

Não entendi  por que usar um terceiro vetor, acredito que seja para atribuir os valores dos `vetor1` e `vetor2`, correto? Caso sim, não é necessário um novo vetor. Para realizar tal intercalação usamos o método `zip()`.

Seu código ficará assim:

```
vetor1 = [0]*5
vetor1[0] = 4
vetor1[1] = -9
vetor1[2] = 78
vetor1[3] = 0
vetor1[4] = 25
print(vetor1)

vetor2 = [0]*5
vetor2[0] = 8
vetor2[1]= 2
vetor2[2] = 34
vetor2[3] = 90
vetor2[4]= 200
print(vetor2)

v3 = [0] * 5

def zipar(v1,v2):
    zipar = []
    for x,y in zip(v1, v2):
        zipar.append(x)
        zipar.append(y)
    return zipar



ListaZipada = zipar(vetor1, vetor2)

for i in ListaZipada:

    print(i ,end=" " )
```

Saída:

```
[4, -9, 78, 0, 25]                                                                          
[8, 2, 34, 90, 200]                                                                         
4 8 -9 2 78 34 0 90 25 200
```

Usei como base está [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/122582/110782), recomendo ler ela e a documentação sobre o método [zip()](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip)

Observe que houve uma modificação no último `print(i ,end=" " )` para obter a saída em uma única linha.

Recomendo a leitura: [Há uma maneira de imprimir tudo sem a quebra de linha?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/146080/h%C3%A1-uma-maneira-de-imprimir-tudo-sem-a-quebra-de-linha)

Comment: Fiquei confuso com a necessidade do return. Retirei ele do código e verifiquei que o compilador acusa que "zipar" não é um objeto iterável. Então pelo menos já entendi o que o return faz aí, mas não entendi porque ele faz de zipar um objeto iterável.